# Raspberry PI não carrega página

Tags: node.js, angular, raspberry-pi

Desenvolvemos uma página usando Laravel para ser carregada no Raspberry Pi

Carrega normalmente, só que houve a necessidade de mudar de tecnologia. Enão mudamos para angular/cli

A página em angular não conecta.

Dá `Gah! your tab just crashed`, se eu tentar acessar a api em nodejs pela barra de endereço do navegador firefox do rasp ele não conecta.

O mesmo sistema foi testado em outros computadores e carrega normal

O Raspberry PI tem alguma limitação para carregar páginas feitas com angular?

Comment: Qual a versão do navegador que você está usando? E não aparece nada no console?

Comment: Você tem o ambiente com node configurado no raspberry?... Como tá startando o projeto?

Comment: O navegador é o Firefox ESR 52.9.0 (32 bits)

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim Não. O node está no servidor.